# Making a standalone solution of Node.js server

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, web-hosting

Node.js seems like a perfect solution for creating an API for my Android application. I want it to be hosted on my own web domain, without using any commercial solutions like Heroku, Firebase, AWS. Running server on localhost seems pretty straightforward, but finding a solution on how i could host it on my own server is a problem.

When purchasing your own domain, what should you look for in terms of supported technologies when you want to host Node.js application, using a MongoDB database, that also has to deal with great amount of media stored? Is there any alternative that doesn't involve using cloud solutions, but creating your own back end solution that allows being in total control of your hosted content, what is installed and how it works?

Comment: Here is some help if you can get your service from digital ocean: https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-host-a-mean-stack-app-on-digital-ocean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you can use a VPS  (Virtual private server). You can have your own Operating system installed, and manage it as your own machine, installing everything you need, and publish there whatever you want. 
I have something like you are looking for with OVH (check it here https://www.ovh.es/vps/vps-ssd.xml). I think they have one of best prices and it works fine.